# Django no reverse match found when passing parameters in {% url %}

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I have the following url conf:

```
      url(r'^tournaments/(?P<tournament_id>\d+)/imports/$',
         'club.apps.main.views.imports_view',
         name='imports_tournament'),
```

And the following template tag:

```
{% url 'imports_tournament' tournament.id%}
```

However, this always raises no reverse url match found error.

Django version is 1.5, so the single quoted syntax should work..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include these urls in url.py?

Comment: Change `tournament.id` to `1`, raises again?

Comment: Are you using a namespace in the root url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an argument to the `url` tag, it assumes you are passing in a positional argument.  Your url view takes a *keyword argument*, so you need to be explicit:

```
{% url 'imports_tournament' tournament_id=tournament.id %}
```

Comment: well... it's working now, after rebooting the server. I wasn't explicit, but this seems like a better practise